# How to set currency and 1000 separator in the expression of ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a SSRS report. In this report I am using 2 datasets (DataSet1, DataSet2). DataSet1 is the table with all the actual dollar amount charged to the client. Dataset2 is has another dollar amount which is the base amount. Everything is working great except I cannot get the amounts from DataSet2 to have a "$" or 1000 separator. I have already tried making the setting to "currency" and "1000 separator" in the placeholder properties, but that did not work. I think this is due to using 2 datasets. I am using the below expression:

```
=join(Lookupset(Fields!size_code.Value,Fields!s_size_code.Value,Fields!s_tech_amount.Value, "DataSet2"),",")
```

I am having difficulty figuring out how to set this number to currency with 1000 separator in the expression for my DataSet2 numbers. The DataSet1 numbers are working perfectly with the currency and 1000 separator that were set in the placeholder properties. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posted expression is returning a string value that consists of the concatenated (join does NOT sum) values of Fields!s_tech_amount from the LookupSet.

The currency formatting can not be applied to a string value.
You can look up how to sum up the values from a LookupSet [here](https://salvoz.com/posts/2013-05-27-sum-result-of-ssrs-lookupset-function.html).
The currency formatting is only applied to numeric data types.